# Nextjs 13 generateMetadata function not being invoked

Tags: next.js13

I am trying to get some data in the generateMetadata function to set metadata for the page.

However, it appears that the function is not being invoked.  Not sure what I have setuop incorrectly.

Here is the function.

```
export async function generateMetaData({ params }){
  console.log("GENERATE MetADATA - slug: " + params.slug);
  post = await getPost(params.slug);
  console.log("GENERATE MetADATA: " + post.title);
  return {
    title: post.title,
    description: post.metadata.teaser
  }

}
```

Not sure if it is related to the call to the function to get the blog post... which is here.

```
async function getPost(slug: string) {
  const data = await Promise.resolve(
    cosmicClient.objects.findOne({
      type: "posts",
      slug: slug,
    })
  );

  let result:Post = await data.object;
  console.log("GET POST: " + result.title);

  return result;
}
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

I had to export as a constant ... then it worked

```
export const generateMetadata = async (props: Props): Promise<Metadata> => {
```